# What is the use case for generator expression on target_include_directories?

Tags: cmake, header-files

I've seen in multiple places references to using generator expressions when defining include directories, so you can define different places for the includes during compilation and during installation. For example:

```
# Define headers for this library. PUBLIC headers are used for
# compiling the library, and will be added to consumers' build
# paths.
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE src)
```

I'm building a library project and since I'm using standard paths (`lib/` for the static library and `include/` for the public headers), I was hoping to get away by setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and using a simple `install()` call, such as:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${MY_INSTALL_DIR}")
install(TARGETS myLibrary ARCHIVE PUBLIC_HEADERS)
```

My expectations were that the `DESTINATION` would be the default for both, so I'm just telling CMake to install these kind of files. Of course it doesn't work and I need to explicitly set the destination for both libraries and header files.

So the question remains: what is the use case for the generator expressions at the beginning, if I don't seem to be able to use the `INSTALL_INTERFACE` anyway?

---

This is my sample CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.1)
project(my_library C)

FILE(GLOB SOURCE_FILES src/*.c)
add_library(my_library ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(my_library PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

set(OUTPUT_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/output")
set(INSTALL_DIR "${OUTPUT_DIR}/my_library")
set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR "${INSTALL_DIR}/lib")
set(INSTALL_INC_DIR "${INSTALL_DIR}/include")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${INSTALL_DIR}")
install(TARGETS my_library ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" DESTINATION include)
# I was hoping I could do, after setting the headers with the INSTALL_INTERFACE generator expression
#install(TARGETS my_library ARCHIVE PUBLIC_HEADERS)
```

Comment: `I need to explicitly set the destination for both libraries and header files` - Can you show the code how you did that?

Comment: Kamil Cuk, I'll edit the question with the barebones of my CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generator-like expressions `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` and `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` are used by CMake for distinguishing things, different for the **build tree** and for the **install tree**.

When building the project itself, `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` is used but `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` is not.

When creating an **export file** with the [install(EXPORT)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#export) command, things listed in `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` will be included into it, but things in `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` won't.

But the creation of an **export file** with the [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html) command uses `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>`, but does not use `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>`.

Other for differentiate build and install trees expressions `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` and `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` are not used.

E.g. `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` does **NOT** affect the `install(TARGETS .. PUBLIC_HEADERS)` command.

Comment: target_include_directories specifies include directories to use when compiling a given target. Why we use Install interface (at install time, target_include_directories) does not have function?

Comment: @TonyParker: I don't understand your question. Called with `PUBLIC` keyword `target_include_directories` specified include directories to use **both** when compiling the target and when compiling "consumer" targets (which links with the given target using `target_link_libraries`).

Comment: 'target_include_directories ' functionality is used at compile time when compiling the tagets, BUILD_INTERFACE will be used, makes sense, when INSTALL_INTERFACE will be used? At install time, we just copy the given targets to specificed destination
In my case, I have seen this in many opensource header only libraries e.g. nlohmann json,

Comment: "At install time, we just copy the given targets to specificed destination" - At install time you install not only the library **file**, but also its **headers**. Moreover, the command [install(EXPORT)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#export) installs the **export file**. This file is generated by CMake itself and defines the library target which is shipped (among other properties) with include directories. Exactly those include directories contains `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>`. So, when a consumer project links with the installed target, it can use installed headers.