# When to use BUILD_INTERFACE and INSTALL_INTERFACE generator expressions with target_include_directories?

Tags: c++, cmake

The [`target_include_directories` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories) states the following:

> Include directories usage requirements commonly differ between the build-tree and the install-tree. The `BUILD_INTERFACE` and `INSTALL_INTERFACE` generator expressions can be used to describe separate usage requirements based on the usage location.

I would like to make my CMake library installable, and I'm not sure if that means I should use these generator expressions. Currently, my `src/CMakeLists.txt` contains the following:

```
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mylib)
target_include_directories(mylib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

This allows me to `#include` my library's public headers without specifying the parent directory while still requiring that users of my library do so themselves. My understanding is that this is standard practice for preventing header filename collisions.

That being said, I don't believe this code will work in its current form for installing the library. What is typically the preferred way to go about fixing this?

Comment: I believe the reason is that you may have a different Include folder tree in the installed configuration versus building. Perhaps the INSTALL combines many folders into a smaller number of folders.

Comment: I think this question explains that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729233/what-is-the-use-case-for-generator-expression-on-target-include-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729233/what-is-the-use-case-for-generator-expression-on-target-include-directories)

Comment: Are you planning on installing a cmake configuration automatically created by cmake(`install(EXPORT)`)? If not there's no need to bother with generator expressions. here. Btw: There are multiple things off with the `target_include_directories` commands in the question: The public headers of a lib should be available via the same include path used by targets linking it. Otherwise you cannot include a public header of the lib including another public header of the lib in a source file of the lib.

Comment: Furthermore `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` should be replaced with `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, since this enables the reuse of the `CMakeLists.txt` file as subdirectory of another `CMakeLists.txt` file. Furthermore you don't need to use absolute paths for non-interface include dirs of the build interface; those dir paths are considered relative to the current `CMakeLists.txt` file. `target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE include/mylib)`

Answer (score 0):

The usage you're looking for would be something like this

```
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mylib>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
```

Assuming that somewhere you also have a line something like this

```
install(FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mylib/mylib.h
        DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}")
```